# Inequality for support of plethysm: "slope" of partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions

Let $\lambda$ be an integer partition. We define $$\newcommand{\slope}{\mathrm{slope}}\slope(\lambda) = \begin{cases}\ell(\lambda)/\vert\lambda\vert & \lambda \neq 0 \\ 0 & \lambda=0.\end{cases},$$
where $\ell(\lambda)$ denotes the length of $\lambda$, i.e. the number of nonzero entries in the partition.

For a symmetric function $f \in \Lambda$, we define $$\slope(f) = \max\{\slope(\lambda) : s_\lambda \text{ occurs with nonzero coefficient in $f$}\},$$
where $s_\lambda$ denotes a Schur polynomial.

I claim that for symmetric functions $f, g \in \Lambda$, we have:

- $\slope(fg) \leq \max\{\slope(f),\slope(g)\}$.
- $\slope(f \circ g) \leq \slope(g)$.

**QUESTION:** Is there already a standard name for the invariant I call "slope"? Do these inequalities perhaps already appear in the literature? I am not asking for an argument - I already have a quick proof of both inequalities.

Comment: I assume from the title that $f \circ g = f[g]$ is plethystic substitution?

Comment: @Sam Yes, exactly.

Comment: I cannot check right now whether it is trivial or not: findstat says that there might be some more statistics such that $s(\lambda)/|\lambda|$ satisfies these two inequalities.  These are all conjecturally: St000183: The side length of the Durfee square of an integer partition. St000318: The number of addable cells of the Ferrers diagram of an integer partition. St000459: The hook length of the base cell of a partition. St000783: The side length of the largest staircase partition fitting into a partition.

Comment: (divided by n of course)

Comment: These inequalities are briefly discussed in Proposition 2.5.10 and Corollary 2.5.12 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.07664 .